# Renews threshold and Renews (last min)

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I am testing a spring-cloud eureka server and client.
I have a simple question about the default configuration (server & client).

On the server side, the renew threshold is equal to 3.
On the client side, it sends a heartbeat every 30 seconds (a maximum of 2 per minute).

When I look at the registry dashboard, when the `waitTimeInMswhenSyncEmpty` is over, I see the following warning message:

```
EMERGENCY! EUREKA MAY BE INCORRECTLY CLAIMING INSTANCES ARE UP WHEN THEY'RE NOT. RENEWALS ARE LESSER THAN THRESHOLD AND HENCE THE INSTANCES ARE NOT BEING EXPIRED JUST TO BE SAFE
```

When I look at the code, the test  `getNumOfRenewsInLastMin() <= numberOfRenewsPerMinThreshold` is always true `(2 <= 3)`

Why is the default configuration, it seems weird because it constantly generates a warning!

If there is anyone who can give me an explanation. I think I've missed something…

Comment: I see `numberOfRenewsPerMinThreshold > 0 && getNumOfRenewsInLastMin() > numberOfRenewsPerMinThreshold`. which works out to `2 > 3 = false`. Where are you looking?
https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/blob/a54991b8fe121bc39b2b1257b0c57f19ff0ccd30/eureka-core/src/main/java/com/netflix/eureka/registry/PeerAwareInstanceRegistryImpl.java#L465

Comment: Could there be a problem between the method isBelowRenewThresold() (which is correct IMHO) and the FTL usage <#if isBelowRenewThresold>. Could it be that the FTL uses a method that returns a number where a boolean is expected?

Comment: Sorry, please ignore my last answer. It seems to work correctly. My eureka console shows me that the renews (4) are indeed lower than the threshold (5). Since I have 2 clients, the renews will normally be 4. The big questionis, why the threshold is greater than the expected renews? This seems to be the case at this question here as well

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem and investigated it a little bit. The root cause for the warning message is that the renews are exactly 1 lower than the threshold.

It occurs when you start a plain eureka server and do not register any clients. It will get a 1 at the Renews threshold.
When you now register a client, the 2 from the client are just added to the one that is already there. Thus making the Renews threshold now 3 and thats higher than the renews can ever get with one client. Wait a few minutes (about 4min) and the warning will appear.

My application.yml is:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: service-registry
server:
  port: 8761
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
          defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
```

I'm using Brixton.RC1.

Found two other SQ questions in the same topic:

[Understanding Spring Cloud Eureka Server self preservation and renew threshold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33921557/understanding-spring-cloud-eureka-server-self-preservation-and-renew-threshold)

[Spring Eureka server shows RENEWALS ARE LESSER THAN THE THRESHOLD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35996481/spring-eureka-server-shows-renewals-are-lesser-than-the-threshold)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some details :

You could find the test allowing to display the message in this file below.

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server/src/main/resources/templates/eureka/navbar.ftl

The value of the 
"isBelowRenewThresold" comes from the code below :

model.put("isBelowRenewThresold", registry.isBelowRenewThresold() == 1);

The invoked method can be found in the following file :

https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/blob/master/eureka-core/src/main/java/com/netflix/eureka/registry/PeerAwareInstanceRegistryImpl.java

Thank you for your help.

Regards,
Stephane

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problems, I tried this in application.properties.

```
eureka.client.lease.duration=10    
eureka.instance.leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds=5    
eureka.instance.leaseExpirationDurationInSeconds=2
```