# Spring Eureka server shows RENEWALS ARE LESSER THAN THE THRESHOLD

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

In Spring Eureka server after refreshing the dashboard many times the following message appears on screen:

RENEWALS ARE LESSER THAN THE THRESHOLD. THE SELF PRESERVATION MODE IS TURNED OFF.THIS MAY NOT PROTECT INSTANCE EXPIRY IN CASE OF NETWORK/OTHER PROBLEMS.

Can anyone tell me what this message means? Is there any why to disable it?

Comment: According to your other post, this is the reason your instances are not being evicted.

Comment: But what this message means? Could you translate in better words?

Comment: It means you turned self preservation off and it's a warning that eureka may have problems if there are network problems that prevent clients from sending heartbeats.

Comment: But I did not change any configuration, so is it the default one?

Comment: This happened to me when a registered server went down. That is, the service didn't have the expected number of renewals during a given period.

Comment: Maybe this can help you know how it happens. [Understanding Spring Cloud Eureka Server self preservation and renew threshold](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33921557/understanding-spring-cloud-eureka-server-self-preservation-and-renew-threshold)