# How can I kill other instance of my microservice in jhipster-registry

Tags: jhipster

I have an application with one microservice and one gateway, I deploy my war(s) application in my external server in different tomcat

Each time I deploy, I have a new instance of my microservice and a my gateway, it's that normal, and how can I kill the other instances

For jhipster-registry I use heroku.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's normal depending on how you configured your Eureka server in JHipster registry.

You can have a look at comments from [EurekaInstanceConfig](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/blob/master/eureka-client/src/main/java/com/netflix/appinfo/EurekaInstanceConfig.java)
, in particular those for `getLeaseExpirationDurationInSeconds()`.

You'll find also some details in this question:
[Understanding Spring Cloud Eureka Server self preservation and renew threshold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33921557/understanding-spring-cloud-eureka-server-self-preservation-and-renew-threshold)