# how to create multiple instances of eureka services registered into eureka service registry?

Tags: spring-cloud-netflix

I have created eureka service registry and registered services into that. Currently only one instance of a service is running. How to add multiple instances of a same service? I am developing standalone application. And I am accessing services through Rest Template.I am following https://spring.io/guides/gs/service-registration-and-discovery/

Comment: Simply run another instance of eureka client application

Answer (score 12):

If you aim to run multiple instances of one service on a same host, you must:

1. configure Eureka instance-id with a random number
2. configure the service use a random port number

These two must be configured individually, e.g.

```
eureka:
  instance:
    instance-id: ${spring.cloud.client.hostname}:${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}
```

and

```
server:
  port: 0
```

Comment: Since Eureka itself is the discovery server, how would a service discover Eureka server if Eureka's port is randomized?

Comment: @Dojo The "random" port number will not be random in run-time, it will be specified after start up. Of course this "random" port number will be registered to Eureka.

Comment: And how would the client know on which port Eureka is running?

Comment: random port for eureka server??

Comment: @Mr.Q  this current application shown here is the eureka client. Once it start with the random port, it registers itself with the eureka server ( which is separate service that keeps the registry). This configuration does not show the url of the eureka server.

Answer (score 7):

Each instance would need to have a unique `instanceId`, normally configured in `application.yml` using:

```
...
eureka:
   instance:
     metadataMap:
       instanceId: ${spring.application.name}:${server.port}
...
```

Adding the port to the `instanceId` allows to run multiple instances in the same host.

I have also seen adding a random number instead of the port the instance listens on.

I blogged about service registration and discovery using `Jersey`, `Spring`, `Eureka`, `Ribbon` and `Feign` with accompanying source code at http://tech.asimio.net/2016/11/14/Microservices-Registration-and-Discovery-using-Spring-Cloud-Eureka-Ribbon-and-Feign.html

And more recently blogged about how to register and discover multiple versions of a service using `Eureka` and `Ribbon` at http://tech.asimio.net/2017/03/06/Multi-version-Service-Discovery-using-Spring-Cloud-Netflix-Eureka-and-Ribbon.html.

Comment: Cool, good articles, so when using feign, imagine there are more than one instance for the services like 2 instance of "demo-registration-api-1", when I using the `@FeignClient(""demo-registration-api-1")` annotation in the feign client, will these two instance services are consumed?

Comment: Thanks, so is there a balance between this? otherwise these are the duplicated call.

Comment: @LipingHuang of course, load balance is handled by Ribbon, there is no difference with running on multiple machines.

Answer (score 2):

You will definitely need another instance of eureka once you have that here is the official spring-cloud  [documentation](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#_peer_awareness) on eureka peer awareness.

In short all you need to do is make them aware of each other by adding the info about each other in their respective application.yml. Hope this helps. Read the doc to learn in detail.

```
---
spring:
  profiles: peer1
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: peer1
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://peer2/eureka/

---
spring:
  profiles: peer2
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: peer2
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://peer1/eureka/
```

Couple of other links to learn about Eureka [github Issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/203), [Understanding Spring Cloud Eureka Server self preservation and renew threshold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33921557/understanding-spring-cloud-eureka-server-self-preservation-and-renew-threshold). Hope this helps.