# What is the difference between eureka.instance.instance-id and eureka.instance.metadataMap.instanceId?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

What is the difference between *eureka.instance.instance-id* and *eureka.instance.metadataMap.instanceId*? I ran 2 instances of same service on same host (localhost) and to have a unique instanceId, I tried both eureka.instance.instance-id and eureka.instance.metadataMap.instanceId. Both properties worked fine and service instances registered successfully with eureka server.

I found below post where both the option are given

[how to create multiple instances of eureka services registered into eureka service registry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42554653/how-to-create-multiple-instances-of-eureka-services-registered-into-eureka-servi)

So, what is the difference between them and where should I use these properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any as such. We can use both :).

When eureka server asks for instanceId while registering client here is what it gets-

```
@Override
public String getInstanceId() {
    if (this.instanceId == null && this.metadataMap != null) {
        return this.metadataMap.get("instanceId");
    }
    return this.instanceId;
}
```

So, if you set it using eureka.instance.instance-id it returns the same otherwise it tries to find the instanceId from metadata (which is set using- eureka.instance.metadataMap.instanceId).

You can check ***EurekaInstanceConfigBean*** class for more details.

Comment: This was useful. Just to add to where we should use eureka.instance.metadataMap.*
I found in EurekaInstanceConfigBean class
/**
  * Gets the metadata name/value pairs associated with this instance. This information
  * is sent to eureka server and can be used by other instances.
  */

 private Map<String, String> metadataMap = new HashMap<>();

Also, a useful blog on dynamic metadata
[https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2018/01/spring-cloud-service-discovery-dynamic-metadata/](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2018/01/spring-cloud-service-discovery-dynamic-metadata/)