# Spring Cloud Eureka Server : how does Eureka server knows what microservices instances are up?

Tags: spring, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I am working on Spring cloud framework. So each of my microservices will have to register with Eureka server, so Eureka knows the unique id or the application name.

(1)  I have to have more than one instance of same microservice to be registered with Eureka,  How do I achieve that? Microservice is deployed in Cloud Foundry.

(2) When all those instances from same microservices are registered with Eureka, how does Eureka know which instances are active and which not? How often Eureak knows and how Eureka gets this information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each instance sends are heartbeat to the eureka server, by default every 30 seconds.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. And how do I create more than one instance of each microservice?

Comment: just run multiple instances?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42631974/6332074) might help in replicating service instances.