# How to eliminate the "Eureka may be incorrectly claiming instances are up when they're not" warning on Eureka Dashboard?

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

How to eliminate the following message on Eureka server dashboard?
Will it cause any issue to my services?

> EMERGENCY! EUREKA MAY BE INCORRECTLY CLAIMING INSTANCES ARE UP WHEN
>   THEY'RE NOT. RENEWALS ARE LESSER THAN THRESHOLD AND HENCE THE
>   INSTANCES ARE NOT BEING EXPIRED JUST TO BE SAFE.

[image: Eureka dashboard]

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding Spring Cloud Eureka Server self preservation and renew threshold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33921557/understanding-spring-cloud-eureka-server-self-preservation-and-renew-threshold)

Comment: @DarrenForsythe Darren, please update or remove your first in your first comment, because it is not anymore what it pretends to be, at least nowadays.

Answer (score 16):

Sample Disable this warning: 
add this property on **application.properties** file

```
 eureka.renewalPercentThreshold=0.85
```

**OR**

```
 eureka.server.enableSelfPreservation=false
```

But enableSelfPreservation also shows another warning message that you disable it.

Comment: This works and enabling the enableSelfPreservation doesn't show any warning for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

On your EurekaServer configuration properties file, change the value of wait-time-in-ms-when-sync-empty to zero or delete this line, cause default value is zero.

```
eureka:
  server:
    wait-time-in-ms-when-sync-empty: 0
```

Answer (score 3):

if you are using **application.properties** add

> eureka.instance.lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds=0

to your file

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error. make sure you have

`<dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId> <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId> </dependency>`

in your client pom. NOT the server dependency.