# What is the explanation for some elements showed on Spring Eureka UX

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I would like to know what is the meaning of the following elements in the Eureka UX:

1. Lease expiration enabled:
2. Renews threshold:
3. Renews (last min):

[image]
I have read technical documentation from Spring Cloud, but I didn't see a explanation about that values.

In the following link appears the configuration for eureka explained in a proper way:
https://dzone.com/articles/the-mystery-of-eurekas-self-preservation

But I didn't see any article about Eureka UX.

Many thanks in advance.

Juan Antonio

Comment: Please refer to https://thesoftwarefeed.substack.com/p/the-mystery-of-eureka-self-preservation for the latest on this article.

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing the answer:
[Understanding Spring Cloud Eureka Server self preservation and renew threshold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33921557/understanding-spring-cloud-eureka-server-self-preservation-and-renew-threshold)

**Lease expiration enabled:** ??

**Renews (last min):** represents how many renews received from Eureka instance in last minute

**Renews threshold:** the renews that Eureka server expects received from Eureka instance per minute.