# Eureka Client not reflecting manual status of OUT_OF_SERVICE

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I have a manager application that uses Eureka to discover worker applications. Both are using Spring Cloud Netflix and the auto configurations that they provide to do service registration and discovery.

Occasionally the manager marks an instance as `OUT_OF_SERVICE` and some time later (on the order of minutes) marks the same instance as `UP`.

The manager discovers instances using the `CloudEurekaClient`, and then sets its status:

```
@Autowired
private CloudEurekaClient cloudEurekaClient;

...

InstanceInfo instance = cloudEurekaClient.getNextServerFromEureka(WORKER_SERVICE_NAME, false);
cloudEurekaClient.setStatus(InstanceInfo.InstanceStatus.OUT_OF_SERVICE, instance);
// do some work
cloudEurekaClient.setStatus(InstanceInfo.InstanceStatus.UP, instance);
```

This seems to work well. The Eureka server status page shows my instances going from `UP` to `OUT_OF_SERVICE`:

[image]

However, the `CloudEurekaClient` doesn't seem to know that an instance is `OUT_OF_SERVICE`. Instead, using the debugger, I have found that the instance has a status of `UP` and overridenStatus of `UNKNOWN`:

[image]

Note: If I call `cloudEurekaClient.getApplication("worker").getInstances()` it shows the 4 `UP` instances, but no mention of the one that is `OUT_OF_SERVICE`.

Is this expected? I assumed the eureka client would know that an instance is `OUT_OF_SERVICE`, but that's not the behavior I'm seeing. This causes problems for a health indicator I have that uses the `CloudEurekaClient` to show the number of `UP` and `OUT_OF_SERVICE` instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging, the issue appears to be that setting instance status makes an immediate call to the Eureka Server, which is why the server status UI shows the proper status real-time:

```
public void setStatus(InstanceStatus newStatus, InstanceInfo info) {
    getEurekaHttpClient().statusUpdate(info.getAppName(), info.getId(), newStatus, info);
}
```

However, calling `CloudEurekaServer.getNextServerFromEureka()` uses a local cache which is only periodically updated on a timer, which is defined by `EurekaClientConfig.getRegistryFetchIntervalSeconds()`.

So I'm in a race condition where if I set an instance status to `OUT_OF_SERVICE` and try to query the discovery client for an application before the cache is refreshed, the client and server have different views of the instances. If I wait  *registryRefreshInterval* seconds before asking the client for the next server, it correctly ignores the instance that I manually put into `OUT_OF_SERVICE` status.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this race condition? I would wish to be able to force refresh cache on the Eureka clients only for that particular instance on demand-basis. Otherwise, we have to force quick auto cache refresh for all Eureka clients: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50402581/11812518

Comment: @PetarBivolarski I never did figure out a way to solve this, and we moved on to using a different service for discovery.